# Spring - Obtaining the list of resources from remote location protected by login and password

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-batch

In my spring-boot batch appli, i read many xml files from local directory : "c:/infiles/"
And that works well.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MultiResourceItemReader<Situation> multiItemReader() {
  ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
  org.springframework.core.io.Resource[] resources = null;
  try {
    resources = patternResolver.getResources("file:c:/infiles/*.xml");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("error reading files", e);
  } 
  return new MultiResourceItemReaderBuilder<Situation>()
      .name("multiItemReader").delegate(reader())
      .resources(resources)
      .setStrict(false)
      .build();
}
```

Now, files are on a server available via Http. I want to access using Spring's Resource abstraction.
It's a remote secured location and i've to be authentificated : login=username, password=password.

I try access the secured location this way :

```
String resourceUrl = "http://username:password@10.**.**.**/infiles/*.xml";  
resources = patternResolver.getResources(resourceUrl);
```

But i don't reach the files, and i've this error :

```
o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [http://username:password@10.*.*.*/infiles/] in the file system: URL [http://username:password@10.*.*.*/infiles/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: http://username:password@10.*.*.*/infiles/
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your text says http, but your code says smb. Which is it?

Comment: The remote directory is : http://10.99.123.999/infiles/

Comment: But what protocol? How do you access the files manually?

Comment: You should make sure you can access the remote resource (ie create the `org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]` array) before using it in your Spring Batch app. So this is not related to Spring Batch per se. `I tried in vain using jCIFS library`: can you share an error or stacktrace that would help?

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, I can't see from what you shared why the connection fails. You need to check if the remote host is reachable.

Comment: I edited the code and modified my question. I include the user and password to the url. But still not accessing files. I add the error too.

Comment: @Sam i access files by the navigator, so http protocol.
files are on a server available via Http. I want to access using Spring's Resource abstraction.

Comment: When you say you are accessing ok via browser/http, you are accessing a concrete file (like `http://username:password@10.**.**.**/infiles/example.xml` ), not a wildcard, right ?

Comment: @PeterMmm Thks for your answer.
 via browser, i access to : h'ttp://10.*.*.*/infiles/.
Then i fill login and password.
And finally i see the list of files.

Comment: Ok, you see the list of files of the folder, because the remote server is configured for this, but you won't get anything for a wildcard. What Spring does. it abstracts from the file system files to a URL (file://, classpath://) when it runs on the same (local) host (hence your example works), but for http:// URL the **remote** server must handle the wildcard and this is not the usual case.

Comment: I think that it possible to load resource from URL. The problem here is the authentication ? So, are there any solution in this case ?

Comment: Possible ? Of course ! But not with that method. What do you think will say this message `cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system` ?

Comment: cannot be solved to absolute file, means that it's expected as a reltive file path. Isn't it ?

Comment: @PeterMmm The other method is one that loads files from relative location (http)  ? but how ?

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand, you want to read some XML data from a remote host and turn them into a `Situation` objects in your code.

For this purpose you are using an abstraction layer for "resources" with `MultiResourceItemReader`.

The problem is that MultiResourceItemReader#resources is set to an object that is not aware of remote (http) resources. It works well for "local file" access, but cannot access a remote service for that. So it tells you `...because it does not reside in the file system`.

Usually you won't get any meaningful with a http request to `/infiles/*.xml` (or the server really has a mapping and response with the list of files).

You will need a remote web service that gives you the list of files and then you can download each resource of that list. This may do Spring's web client, even with XML formatted data: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient

Comment: Thks a lot for your help.